# Google account: How to delete related unwanted services?

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management, google

I use my google account for saving YouTube videos. But Google has added a whole bunch of their services onto my account, such as Adwords, documents, calendar, Picasa, talk, checkout, sites, blogger and more. Now I would like to be able to de-select (delete) all those services that I don't want and don't need, is that possible? For example how can I delete the blogger account?

Comment: How would your experience with the Google account be different once these other services were "deleted"? (I'm not trying to be funny by asking this question: The obvious answer - just don't use them - is so very obvious that I suspect that you're really trying to achieve some other effect, that you haven't mentioned.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has become obsolete. People might not be aware that two account management systems were used on YouTube for some time, but for a long time, all the accounts were unified to use Google accounts. Here is one of the blog articles about the transition [Connecting a Google Account to your older YouTube account](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/connecting-google-account-to-your-older) from 2010. Current help article [Use your Google Account for YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/69961?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only service that can be permanently deleted from a Google Account is Gmail. This can be seen under [your Account page](https://www.google.com/settings/) by clicking Services -> Edit. The only option under "Delete a Product" is "Remove Gmail Permanently".

That said, you do not necessarily have to *use* any of the indicated services. They are merely there should you wish.

Comment: As of October 2023, this is not accurate and precise. Go to Google Account > Data and Privacy > Download or delete your data > Delete a Google Service. This will open a page listing only the services having user data. Google products shown in the Google bar menu will not be shown if they haven't stored data.